# Listbox items to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

This should be easy, but I'm failing to do this.
I have listbox with checkbox option turned on. So I'd like to have selected items in one string.
Like this:

```
item1,item4,item9
```

and so on.

Notice that they should be divided by "," and last comma deleted.

Tried something like this, but won't work:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lb1.Items.Count; i++)
    sb.Append(lb1.Items[i].Selected ? lb1.Items[i].Text + "," : "");
TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: shouldn't you be checking the Checked property and not Selected? What listbox control are you using exactly from DevExpress?

Comment: how doesn't it work. you get an error or string looks wrong?

Comment: Atre you using `CheckedListBoxControl`?

Comment: @DavidePiras ASPxListBox

Comment: @EmmanuelN ASPxListBox with selection mode on "CheckColumn"

Answer (score 6):

You could try (uses [`ASPxListBox.SelectedItems`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxListBox_SelectedItemstopic)):

```
var selectedItems = 
    String.Join(",", lb1.SelectedItems.Select(i => i.ToString()));
```

Or if you're using an older version of .NET without LINQ:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();

foreach(object o in lb1.SelectedItems)
    values.Add(o.ToString());

string selectedItems = String.Join(",", values);
```

Comment: No luck with any of those. I'm using VS2008 and devexpress 9.

Comment: @elninho - What happened when you tried the second suggestion? No result? Errors? Syntax issues? Can't help if you're not a little more specific.